# Intellij Idea Ultimate or Intellij Idea Plus PyCharm and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am coding Android Apps, Server-Side Python Code and using Spring Framework. I have a student license for JetBrains. I like things organized, so should i use Intellij Idea with Android and Python Plug-in or PyCharm, Android Studio and Intellij Idea separated.

Is there too much pros of Android Studio and PyCharm over Intellij Idea plug-ins.

Note: I asked that question 'cause previous questions about this subjects are about android and python separately and also not up-to-date. The nearest question is almost 1 year ago.

Edit: My decision is to go with Intellij Idea Ultimate only. I leave the question open in case some expert want to answer that question detailed. But you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30784212/5322553) that help me made my decision.

Long story short: Android Studio and PyCharm can be more up-to-date but the difference is not to much. JetBrains also developing PyCharm, they usually update Python plugin of Idea quickly. Idea is better in terms of Jython. Also, in terms of Android Studio, JetBrains can also add some features that Studio doesn't have. And since new Android Versions are not become widely used too fast, Intellij Idea can apply the changes before it is late. (Both Android Studio and PyCharm based on Intellij Idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android development, just use Android Studio. It’s developed by Google’s Android team (instead of JetBrains) and always has the latest Android-specific stuff that IntelliJ IDEA’s Android plugin might not.

(For server-side Python, I’m guessing the choice of PyCharm or IntelliJ IDEA doesn’t really matter much; they mostly have the same features. But I'm no expert there.)

Comment: in here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/
It says "No. Android Studio and the Android plugin for IntelliJ IDEA are built from the same code, and all of the changes in Android Studio are, and will continue to be, available in IntelliJ IDEA releases."
So, should i use Studio 'cause it is more up-to-date with Android. I mean how much time difference Idea has with Studio.

Comment: That was posted in 2013 when a very *early preview* of Android Studio was released, and the Android IDE landscape was very different. To my understanding things may be a bit different now when Android Studio is the official Android IDE by Google. I don't think latest Android features are always available in IDEA *immediately*.

For any serious Android development I simply recommend Android Studio ([and I’m not the only one](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices#ides-and-text-editors)). Myself I use AS for Android, and IDEA for backend and other stuff.

Comment: And why don't you just **try them** if you really need to know how they differ for Android development? (You already have a licence for IDEA and AS is free, so nothing stops you.)