# Are there any major differences between Android Studio and the IntelliJ platform on which it is built?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I am somewhat new to both IntelliJ and Android Studio. The Android Studio IDE seems to be built directly on top of the IntelliJ platform. Are they the same?

Comment: Most of it will transfer.  There's major additions, but it is built on IntelliJ, and pretty much any feature of IntelliJ exists in AndroidStudio

Comment: This doesn't sound too opinion-based; I mean, yes, "major" is open to interpretation, but I think we can can handle *that*. It's not like the question was "which is better, Eclipse or IntelliJ". Things that exist in Android Studio but not IntelliJ IDEA or vice-versa are **facts**.

Comment: @SamB, exactly.

Comment: (For context: I'm pretty sure that when I posted my previous comment, someone had voted to close this question as "primarily opinion-based".)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Android Studio is based in Intellij, your "learning curve" should not be a problem at all.

Android studio has more "branding" for Android than IntelliJ IDEA. And since it is just an Android IDE, it can be more "focused". There isn't anything you can do in Android Studio that you can't do in Intellij IDEA. But the opposite is not true. There are a number of (non-android) things you can do in IntelliJ IDEA (both the community and ultimate editions) that you cannot do in Android Studio.
[image]

[for more clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30784212/4564200)